# asp.net and HTTP compression - shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, compression

What are my options when it comes to implementing page compression is asp.net.Right now I have a custom home grown httpmodule and its not very mature.

<strike>Google links me to [MbCompression](http://www.codeplex.com/MbCompression). The project has few views and downloads which discourages me a bit.</strike>

Edit: I am under shared hosting, which limits my access to IIS settings

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 has built in support for gzip and deflate compression. So does IIS 6, but it doesn't work very well for dynamic content.

MbCompress is for minifying assets, which is different than HTTP compression.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FastMVC](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/fastmvc) with a little tweaking for dynamic compression with an ASP.NET MVC app on IIS 6. It has worked out well. I don't think there's anything preventing it from being used in a regular ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 1):

MbCompression design primiraly for http compression, and its main target are sites under share hosting. It suit perfectly for your needs.
Check The last code (not The release code)

Answer (score 1):

I hate to do this, but Googling for something like "HTTP Compression ASP.NET" yields many good resources with code. Usually they will have a method that compresses by using a module. Just find one that makes sense to you--I find the CodeProject projects are often useful for stuff like this.

(And watch out that your hoster doesn't later add compressing at the IIS level. Double-compressing breaks the site. But most hosters who don't have it turned on by now, aren't going to turn it on later 'cause they 'aint smart.)